# Plot two sets of data with one y-axis and two x-axes

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I've read several SO answers about setting up two x-axes for data, as well as some tutorials over at mathworks.com, but I don't see a way to do exactly the following:

Plot dataset number one normally.
Create a second x-axis on the top side of the graph, but use the existing y-axis for the next data set.
Plot dataset number two such that it controls the second x-axis (scaling, etc) and does not overwrite or rescale the existing single y-axis.

The reason to do this is that I would like to plot two different sets of histogram-like values based on the same source dataset, so the frequency distributions are similar in magnitudes, but the value of the bin sizes/edges are different.

My fallback is to do a point-slope scaling of the second data set's x-data , but then I would still have to create a second x-axis similar to [How to insert two X axis in a Matlab a plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31009357/how-to-insert-two-x-axis-in-a-matlab-a-plot) .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create a second axes on top of the first (at the same location) which has the [`XAxisLocation`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_xaxislocation) set to `'top'`, has no `Color` so it's transparent, has no yticks, and has it's [`YLim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_xlim) linked to that of the first axes. Additionally, we can link the `Position` values to ensure that if we resize one of the axes, they resize together to maintain their appearance.

```
figure;

% Create the first axes
hax1 = axes();

% Plot something here
xdata = 1:10;
hplot1 = line(xdata, log(xdata));
    
% Create a transparent axes on top of the first one with it's xaxis on top
% and no ytick marks (or labels)
hax2 = axes('Position', get(hax1, 'Position'), ...  % Copy position
            'XAxisLocation', 'top', ...             % Put the x axis on top
            'YAxisLocation', 'right', ...           % Doesn't really matter
            'xlim', [2 20], ...                     % Set XLims to fit our data
            'Color', 'none', ...                    % Make it transparent
            'YTick', []);                           % Don't show markers on y axis
            
% Plot data with a different x-range here

hplot2 = line(xdata * 2, log(flip(xdata)), 'Color', 'r', 'Parent', hax2);

% Link the y limits and position together
linkprop([hax1, hax2], {'ylim', 'Position'});

% Draw some labels
xlabel(hax1, 'Blue Line')
xlabel(hax2, 'Red Line')
ylabel(hax1, 'Some Value')

% Add a legend? Why not?!
legend([hplot1, hplot2], {'Blue', 'Red'})
```

[image]

### Edit by Carl W (the OP)

The code above will cause ugly XTicks when the tick  spacings aren't the same top and bottom.
I found a workaround at [matlab remove only top and right ticks with leaving box on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553720/matlab-remove-only-top-and-right-ticks-with-leaving-box-on) .   I modded the code above slightly to

```
figure
xdata = 1:10;
plot(xdata)
% get handle to current axes
hax1 = gca;
% set box property to off 
set(hax1,'box','off','color','white')

hax2 = axes('Position', get(hax1, 'Position'),'box','off', ...  % Copy position
            'XAxisLocation', 'top', ...             % Put the x axis on top
            'YAxisLocation', 'right', ...           % Doesn't really matter           
            'Color', 'none', ...                    % Make it transparent
            'YTick', []);
```

#### WARNING: this will **not** work with `plot`, which will override the existing axis assignments.

Since there's no `points` function (stupid MathWorks) I had to do `line(x,y,'linestyle','none','marker','x','parent',hax2)` to get points.

```
hplot2 = line(5:25, log((5:25)), 'Color', 'r', 'Parent', hax2);

linkprop([hax1,hax2],{'ylim','Position'});
```

This gives [image]

Comment: Looks good.  I won't be at a computer w/ MATLAB on it for a few days, but  will probably accept this answer after a quick runthru.   `linkprop` was the Magic Sauce I needed.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft If you want to use `plot` you can modify the axes *after* creation of the plot objects.

Comment: I tried that w/o much luck. Perhaps I was addressing the wrong axis property set at the time.   In any case, I've got it all running smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my hacky way of doing that with `plotyy`.

**Code:-**

```
%Random values for axes
BotttomXaxis = 1:10;
Yaxis =1:3:30;
TopXaxis = (11:20:200).^3;

[ax,H1,H2]= plotyy(Yaxis,BotttomXaxis,Yaxis,TopXaxis)
view([90 -90])

% Now labeling the axes, notice carefully where I have written to write y and x labels.
xlabel('Enter ylabel of the y-axis here')
ylabel(ax(1), 'Enter xlabel of the bottom x-axis here');
ylabel(ax(2), 'Enter xlabel of the top x-axis here');
```

I don't feel the need to add a legend here because the axes and plot colour is already indicating the legend. See figure below:

[image: twoXaxis1]

But if you still want to add legend, you can use the following:

```
legend(H1,'Legend of Bottom X-axis','Location','northeast');
legend(H2,'Legend of Top X-axis','Location','northeast');
%Specifying the Legend location is necessary here
```

**Output:-**
[image: twoXaxis2]

Comment: Ahh, so you rotated the whole thing! :-) .  That's one way of morphing `plotyy` into `plotxx` .

Comment: the new matlab suggests to use yyaxis but I can not rotate the plot after using it. any solution?