# Secondary axes get displaced when resizing figure

Tags: matlab, resize, matlab-figure, axis, colorbar

I am trying to plot a Matlab (R2017a) figure (filled contour + colorbar) with two X axes, on the bottom and top of the graph, with the same scale but different tick marks and labels. Following the suggestions found [here](https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101214-how-can-i-have-a-graph-with-labeled-x-axis-ticks-on-the-bottom-and-top-of-the-graph) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553720/matlab-remove-only-top-and-right-ticks-with-leaving-box-on#20105917), I have achieved it, but when I try to resize the figure window manually or to print it setting certain proportions different from the default ones, e.g.:

```
set(gcf,'PaperUnits','centimeters','PaperPosition',[0 0 30 15])
print(gcf,'-dpng',path,'-r300')
```

the new axes get displaced:

[image: correct axes]

[image: displaced axes]

I have reproduced my issue with the *peaks* example data from Matlab:

```
contourf(peaks)
ax1=gca;
colorbar
set(ax1,'box','off','color','none') % get rid of the box in order not to have duplicated tick marks
ax1_pos = ax1.Position; % position of first axes
ax2 = axes('Position',ax1_pos,... % set the new pair of axes
    'XAxisLocation','top',...
    'YAxisLocation','Right',...
    'Color','none');
set(ax2, 'XLim', get(ax1, 'XLim'), 'YLim', get(ax1, 'YLim')); % set same limits as for ax1
set(ax2, 'XTick', 0:14:42, 'XTickLabels', {'a','a','a','a'},... % set new tick marks and labels for the top X axis.
    'YTick', get(ax1, 'YTick'), 'YTickLabels', []);
```

Curiously enough, if I remove the colobar command and plot just the filled contour, the figure behaves correctly:

[image: Filled contour with no colorbar]

Does anyone know why is this happening (and how could it be solved)? I'm also open to achieve the two-X-axis plot by other means.

Comment: I generally suggest `export_fig` for saving. MATLABs functions are quite crappy.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Hi Ander, thanks for the tip, but the thing is the behaviour I am describing also happens when resizing the figure window manually (I will edit the post to clarify this) so I'm affraid setting the height/width proportions I want before exporting with `export_fig()` does not work.

Comment: What is very strange, is that when I use your minimal example, I get a figure that looks completely fine. Have you tried moving the resizing command as far up as you can (use it ASAP)?

Comment: @FlorisSA try to manually resize the figure after the MCVE OP provided

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that one axis has a colorbar and other does not, and even if you would add a colorbar to both axis, there can be quite a lot of automatic things going on that would resize your axis differently.

However, we can add an event listener and define a function to operate make both axis the same. The listener will make sure it catches the event (resizing) and that it calls the function we define. This is the code I made for that:

```
%% this creates the listener for change of size in the figure
f = figure('SizeChangedFcn',@(src,evn) fixaxis(src));
%% this is your code
contourf(peaks)
ax1=gca;
colorbar
set(ax1,'box','off','color','none') % get rid of the box in order not to have duplicated tick marks
ax1_pos = ax1.Position; % position of first axes
ax2 = axes('Position',ax1_pos,... % set the new pair of axes
    'XAxisLocation','top',...
    'YAxisLocation','Right',...
    'Color','none');
set(ax2, 'XLim', get(ax1, 'XLim'), 'YLim', get(ax1, 'YLim')); % set same limits as for ax1
set(ax2, 'XTick', 0:14:42, 'XTickLabels', {'a','a','a','a'},... % set new tick marks and labels for the top X axis.
    'YTick', get(ax1, 'YTick'), 'YTickLabels', []);

%% this will resize the axis if 2 of them exist
function fixaxis(src)
  ax=findall(src,'Type','Axes');
  if length(ax)==2
  ax(2).Position=ax(1).Position;
  end
end
```

Comment: It works! I did not know this could be done. I will try to learn from it. Many, many thanks for your help (and apologies for my delay answering).

Comment: @Markel no worries. Yeah this is not at all a standard way of using MATLAB ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try also setting the `'PaperPositionMode'` to `'auto'`:

```
set(gcf,'PaperUnits','centimeters','PaperPosition', [0 0 30 15], 'PaperPositionMode', 'auto');
% then print
print(gcf, '-dpng', 'myFile', '-r300')
```

Above command works for me. Produces following result:

[image]

Comment: I'm affraid this is not what I am looking for. Setting `'PaperPositionMode', 'auto'` does indeed produce the result you show, but overrides the previous `'PaperPosition', [0 0 30 15]`, and ideally I want a figure with certain proportions, not a square-like one, because the actual data I want to plot is mainly spread along the X axis.